# Why Head() function showing semicolon separated data in my jupyter note book?

Tags: python-2.x

read the csv file flle using pd.read_csv() method. on displaying , it still in semicolon separated data. I expected table structure

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
import random
import os
df=pd.read_csv("E:\Python\data_full.csv")
df.head()

Actual result :

56;"housemaid";"married";"basic.4y";"no";"no";...
1
57;"services";"married";"high.school";"unknown...
2
37;"services";"married";"high.school";"no";"ye...
3
40;"admin.";"married";"basic.6y";"no";"no";"no...
4
56;"services";"married";"high.school";"no";"no...
In [ ]:

​

Answer (score 0):

When I opened the csv file, each row was shown as single cell. Noticed that the delimiter was ;(semicolon ). I have changed the delimiter to ,(comma) and then the each value in the csv file was displayed in each cell.

Now, the head() method is displaying the results in table structure as expected :)

Is there any limitation to use semicolon as a delimiter in csv file?